# How to change chrome scrollbar padding position?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have div with these properties `div { height:50px; overflow:scroll; direction:rtl; }`

Problem is that on chrome scrollbar is showing where it is supposed to be (on left side), but there is also something like padding added to right side of that div and text is going under scrollbar. 
I read that this is chrome bug, but couldn't find solutions. Is there a way to fix this?

This problem only occurs on chrome, both on mac and windows.

This is example http://jsfiddle.net/3FUUG/1/

Comment: Please add your code and a working example

Comment: Added working example.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding padding-left to the div? Like this:

```
div { height:50px; overflow:scroll; direction:rtl; padding-left: 10px;}
```

Here is its [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zmz6/)